# Cannot convert value of type 'User?' to expected argument type 'String'

Tags: database, firebase

So im trying to check if the current user exist and i get the error: Cannot convert value of type 'User?' to expected argument type 'String'. im assuming i need to convert the User? to String, any ideas?

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
        databaseRef.child("Users").queryOrdered(byChild: "uid").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.hasChild(user){

                print("user does exist")

            }else{

                print("user does not exist")
            }


        })
```

Answer (score 0):

the data types in react native not strict. no data types in react native.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

fixed by inserting "?.uid" on

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
```

to

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
```